# Need copy of original sources.list for 10.04 (64-bit)

Tags: 10.04

Gentlemen, I borked my sources.list and rather than building another VM in order to pull the sources.list file,  I was hoping someone here has a copy I could use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will usually be a backup in /etc/apt called sources.list.save, just rename it.

Also there is a sources.list generator available at [ubuntu sources generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php)

Just select these repositories.  Main, Restricted, Universe, Multiverse, Security and Updates, scroll to the bottom and click Generate List

Comment: sources.list.save has also been modified and is not the original.

Comment: is this http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php any good to you?  a generator, just select your country and the main, restricted, universe, multiverse, security, updates repositories and optionally partner repo

Comment: `repogen.simplylinux.ch` does not support 10.04 any more, and, as such, is no longer the correct answer to this question.